# Reputation bug with privileges

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, privileges

Over at [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) I've just been informed "Congrats, you've gained the privilege to create tag synonyms".

However, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms tells me that this takes 2500 reputation and I only have (at this moment) 2329. Further, it appears I don't actually have the privilege to create tag synonyms.

So, this is a bug, no?

***Update***: So, now I've actually passed the 2500 threshold, and didn't get a notification of such. Not a big deal; just trying to help squash a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this happened you passed 2500 rep only due to someone serial upvoting you (which triggered the privilege notice as well).  These were reversed when our fraud detection caught and reversed it (also recalculating your reputation).  As a result, your reputation went back down  to what it was without those votes and you dipped below the privilege threshold.

By design, we don't want to annoy you with the notice twice, so we don't ever show a privilege notice twice, whatever the cause...for the rarity vs annoyance factor, we think this is the best solution overall.