# Why was I notified of privileges that I don't have?

Tags: support, reputation, notifications, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gained bounty privilege without sufficient reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70371/gained-bounty-privilege-without-sufficient-reputation)

I know that 20 Reputation is required for chat room conversion. This information I found on the privilege page as below,

[image]

However I got this notification of chat privilege as follow, while i have 15 reputation at present.

[image]

I was surprised to see the notification, so I went to a chat room, where system didn't allow me for chat.

[image]

Comment: You had 30 reputation for a period of one second (sufficient enough to trigger the notification), but then your [answer was unaccepted](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10730564/timeline).

Comment: but i can't see that reputation part, even after ticking "show removed posts" @TimStone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tim Stone explained with the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10730564/timeline) link, I found my answer: It wasn't a bug, it was my misunderstanding.

This image explains very clearly that a user first accepted my answer ( Action 1 ) and just moments later unaccepted my answer ( Action 2 ). Meanwhile the notification was triggered.

[image]

However the time between actions ( accepted & unaccepted ) was so minor that it is not showing in my reputation tab, even after I checked "show removed posts". This was the only reason I got confused about the chat notification.

Comment: Yes, but I guess revoke period is very less sometime, that's why it is not in the picture, how ever it should be there @MrLister